# Why don't everybody use ViewGroup.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Because it can be used either with `Relative` or `Linear` layouts. So it could be useful in case we later change from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`.

And it seems `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is not an inherited function from `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

So is there any reason we should use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` over the other one? Is there any layout type specific advantages in using this `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` over the common thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for LinearLayout, and you need to use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` for RelativeLayout, otherwise you will crash. While the constants for `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` are the same, the specific layout params add additional information to the layout params, for example in `RelativeLayout`, the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` stores the rules that you specify as `centerInParent` or `below` or `toRightOf`, etc. If you give it a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, it'll just crash.

For example, this is LinearLayout.LayoutParams

```
    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {
        @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
        public float weight;
```

And this is RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

```
public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams {
        @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout", resolveId = true, indexMapping = {
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ABOVE,               to = "above"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_BASELINE,      to = "alignBaseline"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_BOTTOM,        to = "alignBottom"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_LEFT,          to = "alignLeft"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, to = "alignParentBottom"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,   to = "alignParentLeft"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,  to = "alignParentRight"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,    to = "alignParentTop"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_RIGHT,         to = "alignRight"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_TOP,           to = "alignTop"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = BELOW,               to = "below"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = CENTER_HORIZONTAL,   to = "centerHorizontal"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = CENTER_IN_PARENT,    to = "center"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = CENTER_VERTICAL,     to = "centerVertical"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = LEFT_OF,             to = "leftOf"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = RIGHT_OF,            to = "rightOf"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_START,         to = "alignStart"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_END,           to = "alignEnd"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_START,  to = "alignParentStart"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = ALIGN_PARENT_END,    to = "alignParentEnd"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = START_OF,            to = "startOf"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = END_OF,              to = "endOf")
        }, mapping = {
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = TRUE, to = "true"),
            @ViewDebug.IntToString(from = 0,    to = "false/NO_ID")
        })

        private int[] mRules = new int[VERB_COUNT];
        private int[] mInitialRules = new int[VERB_COUNT];

        private int mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom;

        private boolean mRulesChanged = false;
        private boolean mIsRtlCompatibilityMode = false;

        /**
         * When true, uses the parent as the anchor if the anchor doesn't exist or if
         * the anchor's visibility is GONE.
         */
        @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "layout")
        public boolean alignWithParent;
```

Answer (score 2):

> So is there any reason we should use LinearLayout.LayoutParams over the other one

`LinearLayout` expects a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, as you can see by reading [the source code for `LinearLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java). If you supply something else, like `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, you will crash at runtime with a `ClassCastException`, when `LinearLayout` code tries casting the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: ok i understood, i got confused because of this line, `new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` , didnt notice ViewGroup thing was only for the constants